# Why are shaders called shader?

Tags: graphics, 3d, shader, terminology

I can't find the word in any dictionary, neither in regular ones nor etymology ones. Only Wikipedia says:

> The modern use of "shader" was introduced to the public by Pixar with their "RenderMan Interface Specification, Version 3.0" originally published in May 1988.

I know it's a program that runs on the GPU, but how did the Pixar guys come up with the name *shader* for it?

Comment: I can imagine they chose the word because the purpose of that technique is to add complex "shades" to a plain surface.

Comment: Likely because the classic lighting algorithms are named things like "Blinn shading", "Phong shading", "Gourand shading", etc.

Comment: That's right. And RenderMan had a "shading language" to implement those kinds of shading (and more). And then functions written in a shading language became known as "shaders".

Answer (score 2):

Although `shader` is not part of most dictionaries, the noun `shading` should be. [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shading), for example, defines it as

> a slight variation or difference of color, character, etc.

This is is exactly what a shader does: It allows the programmer to add variations of color to a surface.

Comment: Thank you so muck for the grammar correction, I've learnt a better way to construct a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Shades is a very very very important factor in human vision. It allows recognizing shapes. And it's so because we live in a planet with plenty of shades, because of mainly Sun.

Realism needs shades. The Sun is not the only light. Conclusion: Good coloring implies shading from one or several lights. "Shaders" is the natural name for that programs that do it.